# GetLastError() != oddity

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, error-handling

As part of my C++ project, I'm using a file-managing struct with the WinAPI file management functions.
When searching for a temporary file name, I have a function `OpenNewTempFile()` which will generate a name, attempt to open it via calling another function in the struct, simply `OpenFile()`, and if the file already exists, retry with a different name silently (and infinitely as it loops).
This is `OpenFile()`, and it should only report file-already-exists errors if it's not opening as a temporary file.

[image: GetLastError() oddity]

Can someone explain why the `if` block is executing? The second part of `&&` shouldn't be true.
You can see the current variables in the VS dock below when the block is hit, and what `GetLastError()` returns in the console window above. This is confusing me to bits.

EDIT:
Due to suggestions, I've stored GetLastError in a variable.

[image: Snap with GetLastError() stored]

...well, that just raises more questions. Why is it now 80?

Comment: Please post the source code instead of screenshots

Comment: Can it be that you are comparing signed and unsigned values? What data type does `GetLastError()` return?

Comment: No, do like everyone else does, type your code in afresh with subtle but crucial differences from your real code. (Sarcasm of course)

Comment: @Andrey It seems more informative (and less of a fakesi) to show a screenshot where the variables' contents can be shown in the debugger. Anyway, I'll add it.

Comment: How do you expect us to answer something like this when we can't see what your code *does*? No, it is not more informative to show a screenshot of what you *already checked* in your debugger. If you want us to explain why your code does what it does, then you need to show us your code.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I considered that, hence the cast to DWORD

Comment: @Phi try to replace the function calls. Save the result of `GetLastError()` to a variable and check it individually. To output the result, you are calling the function for the second time now. If anything happens between the calls, they may yield different values.

Comment: @Phi, signedness makes no difference to equality or inequality comparisons, only to greater than or less than comparisons.

Comment: @jalf The only thing that I don't understand is how the other side of && is true in the if block, and all the variables involved in that are shown. GetLastError()'s return can be seen by printf, (which is what Debug is, essentially), and AsTemp is shown in the debugger's locals.

Comment: `GetLastError()` value was changed by another thread?

Comment: Good suggestion @Andrey, it's protected by a CRITICAL_SECTION "&Lock". However, that's the only plausible suggestion thus far, so I'll modify the code to store the result before it hits the if.

Comment: @Andrey: The last error codes are thread-specific, so no.

Comment: Remember that if you're in the Visual Studio debugger, you can use @ERR,hr to display the value of 'GetLastError' in the watch window.  That can be very useful.

Comment: How about `Debug` is some kind of macro, and it ends up reseting the return from `GetLastError` before `GetLastError()` is called. Just guessing, no idea if `Debug` is a macro.

Comment: May `Valid()` alter the error code?

Comment: `bool File::Valid(void) const
{
 return (Handle && Handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE);
}`
Checks non-null and valid, in case I'm haunted by my old fopen methods :)

Comment: @Phi: The only way I can see this happening is if `Debug` is a macro that attempts to create a file that already exists.

Comment: @molbdnilo It's a `#define LogToFile(); LogToConsole()` effectively. It uses `fopen` to open the log file, write the contents with `fprintf`, then `fclose` again. That would explain things. I don't even know why I'm logging to file that way.

Comment: Yep, 80 (ERROR_FILE_EXISTS) is the real value returned, not 183 (ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS), oddly enough. The `fopen()` call must be calling `SetLastError()` when it opens successfully so you can tell if it made a file or opened an existing one. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Phi: Note that `fopen` may call some function internally (like `creat`, for instance) that sets LastError even if `fopen` itself succeeds, but the value of LastError is meaningless in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that there are two "file already exist" codes in Windows. From [CreateFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) documentation:

> ### CREATE_ALWAYS
>
> Creates a new file, always.
>
> If the specified file exists and is writable, the function overwrites
>   the file, the function succeeds, and last-error code is set to
>   **ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS (183)**.
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path, a new file
>   is created, the function succeeds, and the last-error code is set to
>   zero.
>
> For more information, see the Remarks section of this topic.
>
> ### CREATE_NEW
>
> Creates a new file, only if it does not already exist.
>
> If the specified file exists, the function fails and the last-error
>   code is set to **ERROR_FILE_EXISTS (80)**.
>
> If the specified file does not exist and is a valid path to a writable
>   location, a new file is created.

You use the `CREATE_NEW` flag (rightly), so you should expect the 80 code to show up.

Comment: Ah, the function should _succeed_ if it overwrites an already existing file, so testing for ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS when it fails is pointless.
It's confusing having a return method as an error code.

Comment: GetLastError() was changed by the Debug() macro, which opened a file to log to it, and thus removed the accuracy of the GetLastError() bug. Thus GetLastError() was changed within the call in the if condition, and the call inside the actual if code block. Read the comments on the question to find how the answer was solved in more detail. Thanks guys.

Comment: It's confusing, but it's not the only WinAPI function that behaves such way. `CreateMutex`, for example, may also set last error to `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` in some cases, which are considered as "function succeeds".

Answer (score 0):

> Why is it now 80?

80 means "The file exists" and you are trying to `CREATE_NEW` if `AsTemp == true` and `AsTemp` is `true` in your case.

Comment: What decides which of 183 or 80 is returned?

Comment: I generally use the Error Lookup tool under the Tools menu. But good tip. +1

Comment: I deleted the comment because I misunderstood you question and @jpalecek provided a better answer, but for those who'll read this thread later - the tip was about adding `,hr` after variable name in the watch window to see human readable error description.